# The assertion : A implies non(A), is it false?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have  proved that $(1) \; A \to B.$

But I want prove that:

$(2)\; B \to \neg A.$

From (2), is (2) a false assertion? Because if (2) is true, this means that:

$A \to \neg A = \lnot A \lor \lnot A \equiv \lnot A$ is true.

Comment: If (1) and (2) are correct then (3) is also correct by transitivity of implication, which would suggest A is false

Comment: If $A$ is false then $A \to B$, $B\to \lnot A$ and $A \to \lnot A$ will all be true.   But $A \to \lnot A$ can only be true if $A$ is false.  If you have *successfully* proven $A \to B$, I do not know if you can successfully prove $B \to \lnot A$, but if you *can* you will have successfully proven $\lnot A$.

Answer (score 0):

So we start with the proven implication:

\begin{align*}
&A \Rightarrow B \\
\end{align*}

We then consider the new implications:

\begin{align*}
B \Rightarrow !A\\
A \Rightarrow !A \\
\end{align*}

This proves that A has to be False, because False statements can imply True statements, but True statements cannot imply False statements.

Comment: False statements can imply true statements, so if A is false then there is no fallacy

Comment: @Henry That is true, but the same statement can only be true or false, and here A has to be both true and false.

Comment: No. You can't conclude $B$ from $A\to B$ if $A$ is false. So $A\to \lnot A$ isn't a fallacy, it's a proof that $A$ is false.

Comment: @MJD That is true, but he does not say that he has B. He says that B implies not A.

Comment: @MJD You are right. I thought I knew how this all worked, guess not. Do you want to add this as an answer, or should I add it to my answer?

Comment: Right. But he has $A\to \lnot A$. If $A$ were true you would be able to conclude $\lnot A$ and this would be a contradiction. But as $A$ is not true, you can't conclude anything from it.

Comment: You can revise your answer.

Comment: @MJD, I will do that.

Comment: @Henry, You are also right, I updated my answer.

Comment: Assume that, B is true then: 
    A implies B, is true
    and this implies that
    A and B , is true......(4)
    But (4) is the negation of :
    B implies non (A)......(5)
    Thus (5) is false, is it correct this proof?

Comment: @Martin, If B is true, and A implies B, then A can be either True or False, because False statements can imply True statements. Think of it in this way: If it is raining, then it is wet outside. If I know it is wet outside I do not necessarily know that it is raining. It could be that a sprayer is on instead and that it is not raining.

Answer (score 0):

> From (2), is (2) a false assertion? Because if (2) is true, this means that:
>
> A→¬A=¬A∨¬A≡¬A
> is true.

Why would proving $\lnot A$ be a contradiction?  Were you *told* that $A$ had to be true?

....

If not, then proving $A \to B$ and $B \to \lnot A$ will prove that $A$ is false.  Which isn't a contradiction.

Notice $P \to Q$ and $P \to \lnot Q$ is *not* a contradiction.  The can both be true but they are both true if and only if $P$ is false.

Likewise $P \to \lnot P$ is also not a contradiction.  It will be true if and only $P$ is false.

So $A \to B$ and $B \to \lnot A$  will have proven $A \to \lnot A$ which isn't a contradiction if $A$ is false.  However if you prove that both $A \to B$ and $B \to \lnot A$, that that is a proof that $A$ is false

The following  may be useful:

$P \to \lnot P \iff \lnot P$

$P \to Q \iff \lnot Q \to \lnot P$

$(P\to Q)\land (P\to \lnot Q) \iff \lnot Q$

$(P \to Q) \land (\lnot P \to Q)\iff Q$

$(P \to Q) \land (Q \to \lnot P) \iff \lnot P$.

etc.

Also if $Q$ is true then $X \to Q$ is always true.

And if $P$ is false then $P \to X$ is always true.

So for *any* $X$ then $A \to X$ and $X\to \lnot A$ will be consistent and will both be true whenever $A$ is false (but if $A$ is true then one will be true and the other false depending upon whether $X$ is true or false.)